# Why with `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe` the execution of coroutine is immediate whereas with `loop.create_task` it's not (loop in other thread)

Tags: task, python-asyncio, python-multithreading, event-loop

I am developping a tool that handles HTTP requests and put the request body on a discord channel. It is a Python script which runs a Discord bot and a Flask app.

I have 3 threads and 3 modules: the main one which runs the thread for `client.run()` (in bot.py) and an other for `app.run()` (server.py):

`main.py`:

```py
from bot import start_bot
from server import start_server
import concurrent.futures


if __name__ == "__main__":

    with concurrent.futures.ThreadPoolExecutor() as executor:
        futures = [executor.submit(start_bot), executor.submit(start_server)]
```

`server.py`:

```py
from flask import Flask, request
import asyncio


app = Flask(__name__)

@app.route("/", methods=["POST"])
def handle_post_request():
    
    content = request.get_data().decode("utf-8")
    message = json.loads(content)["message"]
    
    from bot import send_msg, client
    asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_msg(message), client.loop)

    return "OK"

def start_server():
    app.run(port=..., host=...)
```

`bot.py`:

```py
from discord.ext import commands


client = commands.Bot()

async def send_msg(msg:str) -> None:
    channel = client.get_channel(...)
    await channel.send(msg)

def start_bot():
    client.run(...)
```

Note that it works perfectly. It works also if I replace the line `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe(send_msg(message), client.loop)` with `client.loop.create_task(send_msg(message))`.

The thing I struggle to understand is **why in this last case (I mean using `loop.create_task()` instead of `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()`) the `send_msg()` coroutine starts to execute after a few seconds (it's not constant, this delay can be between 1 and 30 seconds) whereas `asyncio.run_coroutine_threadsafe()` immediately executes it**.